# Using busybox shell, i'm trying to divide the output of a cat command by 1000, as a float

Tags: sh, posix, busybox

I am trying to run the following command with two-point precision (because I want to convert it to Fahrenheit).

```
echo "$(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/type) $(($(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp)/1000))"
```

Extra points to help me add the code to convert it to Fahrenheit!

Again, this is Busybox, not bash, so available commands/syntax are somewhat limited.
THANKS!!!

*I promise I'm not being lazy on purpose. It's over 100 degrees Fahrenheit here today, I have a terrible dehydration headache, so my brain isn't working at total capacity. All help is apprecaited*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

busybox provides `bc` which is arbitrary precision. Its `scale` command sets how many digits after the decimal point to show on output.

`/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*` can return more than one directory, so you should use a loop.

C to F conversion is: F = 32 + 9C/5

```
for z in /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*; do
    echo "$(cat $z/type) $(echo "scale=2;32+9*$(cat $z/temp)/5000"|bc -l)"
done
```

Comment: Awarding the answer for fully writing out the code. My heat-addled brain thanks you immensely!

Answer (score 0):

`sh` doesn't do floats, but busybox implements `bc`, which uses `scale` to set precision.  Assuming you've assigned C a Celcius temp,

```
echo "scale=2; 32+9*$C/5" | bc
```

you can test various randomly generated values with something like

```
echo "scale=2; 32+9*$((RANDOM%50))/5" | bc
```